# Django ORM bulk_create 1:1 related models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

I've seen similar questions asked, but vague answers were provided so I would appreciate any feedback.

I want to do a bulk create on some related 1:1 objects.

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
class A(models.Model):

class B(models.Model):
    A = models.ForeignKey(A)

all_a = []
all_b = []
for i in range(10000):
    new_a = A()
    new_b = B(A=new_a)
    all_a.append(new_a)
    all_b.append(new_b)

with transaction.atomic():
    A.objects.bulk_create(all_a)
    B.objects.bulk_create(all_b)
```

But I'm guessing the A models need to be written to the DB and the actual PK returned and associated with B models before I can write them.

Has anyone got a good suggestion on how to do this efficiently?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What database are you using? There's a good solution for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Using Postgres, but will probably move to a TS db like TimeScale at some stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PostgreSQL this is straightforward, since the `bulk_create()` for `A` [will populate](https://github.com/django/django/blob/31408446b3880115a1f121230ce5e32e4e066a4b/django/db/models/query.py#L478) each object's `pk`.

```
with transaction.atomic():
    all_a = [A() for _ in range(1000)]
    A.objects.bulk_create(all_a)

    all_b = [B(A=new_A) for new_a in all_a]
    B.objects.bulk_create(all_b)
```

On other databases this will be much trickier, because `bulk_create()` [doesn't get the ids](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) of the newly created objects.

> If the model’s primary key is an `AutoField` it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as `save()` does, unless the database backend supports it (currently PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create the A instance beforehand. Try like this:

```
all_a = []
all_b = []
new_a_list = []

for i in range(10000):
    new_a = A()
    all_a.append(new_a)
with transaction.atomic():
    new_a_list = A.objects.bulk_create(all_a)

for new_a in new_a_list:
    new_b = B(A=new_a)
    all_b.append(new_b)

with transaction.atomic():
    B.objects.bulk_create(all_b)
```

Comment: Can I guarantee the order of the returned set from the first bulk_create to match a and b records?

Comment: as far as I tested, yes.

Comment: It has follwed the order in which the list passed as parameter for bulk creation.